# MLE of a random sample Y1,...,YN from a bin(n,p) distribution

Tags: statistics

I have a random sample $Y_1,..., Y_N$ from a $bin(n,p)$ distribution and I'm supposed to show that the MLE is:

$\hat{p}$=$\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i \over Nn$.

But when I take the MLE of the binomial distribution this is what I get:

$f(x)=(nCp)p^Y(1-p)^{n-Y}$

$L(p)=$$\prod_{i=1}^n (nCp)p^{Y_i}(1-p)^{n-Y_i}$

$lnL(p)$=$(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_iln(p)$ + $(n-\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$)$ln(1-p)$)

$dlnL(p)\over dp$=$1\over p$ $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ + $1\over (1-p)$$(n-\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i) =0$

......

$\hat{p}$=$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\over n$

I'm not sure where the N comes in the denominator. Where did I go wrong?  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: The first wrong line is the line with LHS $f(x)$. What are you trying to say there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood of observing a sample $\boldsymbol y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_N)$ where each $Y_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)$ for a known constant $n$ is $$L(p \mid \boldsymbol y) = f(\boldsymbol y \mid p) = \prod_{i=1}^N \binom{n}{y_i} p^{y_i} (1-p)^{n-y_i}.$$  Then the log-likelihood is proportional to $$\ell(p \mid \boldsymbol y) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N y_i \log p + (n-y_i) \log(1-p) = N \bar y \log p + N(n - \bar y) \log(1-p),$$ where $\bar y = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i$ is the sample mean.  Thus $$\frac{\partial \ell(p \mid \boldsymbol y)}{\partial p} = \frac{N\bar y}{p} - \frac{N(n-\bar y)}{1-p}$$ and $\ell$ has a critical point at $$p = \frac{\bar y}{n} = \frac{1}{Nn}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i.$$  All that is left is to verify that this critical point is in fact the MLE.

Comment: So in order to verify that the critical point is the MLE, I use the 2nd derivative test?

Comment: That is one way, yes.  Other ways exist as well, such as evaluating the log-likelihood at the critical points and endpoints.

Comment: @heropup I know this is really old answer , but one question, since a binomial has 2 parameters don't we have to find partial derivatives and find estimators for both n and p? Or is it in your case n is assumed known?  Don't quite understand this would be great if you could help me out

Comment: @Rivaldo Because the provided answer for $\hat p$ contains $n$, it was presumed that $n$ is a known and fixed constant; otherwise, the given answer would not be an estimator.  If $n$ and $p$ are both unknown, then the problem becomes much more difficult, since $p$ is continuous and $n$ is discrete.  We would set $p = \hat p$ in terms of $n$ as we solved above, then presumably try to find $n$ such that $L$ is greatest.